# Keys and indexes to string - implode with a twist

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, implode

Snippet:

```
$temp = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    // This line varies, from HTML to URLs, to anything in between
    array_push($temp, "<b>$key:</b> $value"); 
}
$request = implode('<br/>', $temp); // Glue also varies depending on needs
unset($temp);
```

This is a getaway from the usual `$string .= 'blah<br/>'`. Never mind the `rtrim`.

Can anyone show me a better way to achieve above without use of a temp array and possibly without a loop? Bonus points for not using above code in a function, lambda acceptable though.

P.S. While writing this question I have found a wonderful [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query). One down, one to go.

Edit:

What result should look like:

```
<b>Title: </b> Value</br>
<b>Title2: </b> Value2</br>
<b>Title3: </b> Value3
```

Or with different settings (not required, but shows possibility):

```
key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

I am trying to improve my code, I use the above snippet everywhere.

Comment: what you want to do? It's not clear for me.

Comment: We are happy for you! :)

Comment: Can anyone show me a better way to achieve above without use of a temp array and possibly without a loop? Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: There are two options, you listed both. Now you need to decide what you prefer. You could abbreviate with `$temp[] = ....`. But you can't dismiss the loop if you have an unknown number of entries. `http_build_query` will use a loop too, to build a query string.

Comment: Modify your question what you want to achieve your code outputs `<b>a:</b> val<br/><b>b:</b>` if `$data = array('a' => 'val', 'b' => 'val');` what do you need it for? For such things there is no need to create new temp array nor use implode function should simple echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer: There are some ways, but:

Loops & arrays are the best friends of any programmer.

They provide pretty good readability, reusability and generally are considered to be a right way for performing pretty much the same actions.

You may also take a look on `array_map` or `array_walk`. Less code, but it is a loop anyways.

```
array_walk($data, function($value, $key){
  $temp[] = "<b>{$key}:</b> {$value}" ;  //Shorthand for array_push is $arr[] = $value ;
}) ;
```

Comment: Please escape your outputs.

Comment: I like it - minimal, neat and solves the problem. 
@Jack, we can assume a safe source for the sake of the solution.

Comment: @KirillGordeenko That should never be the assumption; as the answer is seen by others in future, it's better that the output is escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is one way; yay for "one-liners":

```
$data = ...;

echo join("\n", array_map(function($key) use ($data) {
    return sprintf('<b>%s:</b> %s',
        htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        htmlspecialchars($data[$key], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );
}, array_keys($data)));
```

You basically map the keys using a closure that binds the original array as well so that you have access to both the key and value in each invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will prefere your solution:

```
$data = range('a', 'e'); // some data
$request = ''; // empty string
array_map(function($value, $key)use(&$request, $data){
    static $i = 1;
    if($i == count($data)){
        $request .= "<b>$key:</b> $value";
    }else{
        $request .= "<b>$key:</b> $value<br/>";
    }
    $i++;
}, $data, array_keys($data));

echo $request;
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/VuasSq)

---

A solution with a loop but without $temp array:

```
$data = range('a', 'e'); // some data
$request = ""; // empty string
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $request .= "<b>$key:</b> $value<br/>"; // add to string
}
$request = substr($request,0,-5); // remove last <br/>
echo $request; //output
```